# Getting the count of total news in other table

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am having problem to getting the total count of new from another table , I am using this code below:

```
$news_cat = array(); 
$news_cat = DB::query("select * from news_cat order by id");

foreach($news_cat as $cc){
    DB::query("select news_id from info_news where cat_id=%i",$cc['id']);
    $news_cat['all_news_in_cat'] = DB::count();

}
$smarty->assign('news_cat', $news_cat);
$smarty->display("blog.tpl");
```

What I want to print is ( `all_news_in_cat` ) in the tpl file

Regards,
amer

Answer (score 0):

you could change out your SQL a bit. try this:

```
SELECT cat_id, count(news_id) from info_news group by cat_id
```

that should return back alll in one line

Comment: it looks like he need the information from the news_cat table also check this code.  `$news_cat = DB::query("select * from news_cat order by id"); ... ; $smarty->assign('news_cat', $news_cat);`